# How to load data from json in Vue and display these data in components?

Tags: json, vue.js, import

I'm making a single page website. I'm new to Vue and I'm quite confused on these. I don't have a backend server yet, so I write some data in json files in order to show on different components. The json files are named as employee id, like 12231.json. Where should I place the code to load these json data? And how can every components get the data?

I have a headerNav.vue component that shows on every page. Should I Place the code there?

headerNav.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="headermuseui">
    <mu-appbar style="width: 100%;" color="#00BCD4">
      <mu-button icon slot="left" @click="open = !open">
        <mu-icon value="menu"></mu-icon>
      </mu-button>HOME
      <div></div>
      <mu-button flat slot="right" v-on:click="switchPage('messages')">
        <mu-icon value="search"></mu-icon>
      </mu-button>
      <mu-button flat slot="right" v-on:click="switchPage('expense')">
        <mu-icon value="search"></mu-icon>
      </mu-button>
      <mu-button flat slot="right" v-on:click="getJsonFile('12231')">
        <mu-icon value="search"></mu-icon>
      </mu-button>
    </mu-appbar>

    <mu-drawer :open.sync="open" :docked="docked" :right="position === 'right'">
      <div>
        <div class="x">
          <img class="y mdui-img-circle" src="..\assets\picture\nuuneoi.png">
        </div>
        <img height="160px" src="..\assets\picture\nav_header_bg.jpg">
      </div>
      <mu-list>
       
        <mu-divider/>
        <router-link :to="{'name':'index'}">
          <mu-list-item button :ripple="false">
            <mu-list-item-action title="Home">
              <mu-icon value="home"></mu-icon>
            </mu-list-item-action>
            <mu-list-item-title>Home</mu-list-item-title>
          </mu-list-item>
        </router-link>
        <router-link :to="{'name':'login'}">
          <mu-list-item button :ripple="false">
            <mu-list-item-action title="Message">
              <mu-icon value="message"></mu-icon>
            </mu-list-item-action>
            <mu-list-item-title>Message</mu-list-item-title>
          </mu-list-item>
        </router-link>
        <router-link :to="{'name':'login'}">
          <mu-list-item button :ripple="false">
            <mu-list-item-action title="Record">
              <mu-icon value="event_note"></mu-icon>
            </mu-list-item-action>
            <mu-list-item-title>Record</mu-list-item-title>
          </mu-list-item>
        </router-link>
        <router-link :to="{'name':'login'}">
          <mu-list-item button :ripple="false">
            <mu-list-item-action title="setting">
              <mu-icon value="settings"></mu-icon>
            </mu-list-item-action>
            <mu-list-item-title>Settings</mu-list-item-title>
          </mu-list-item>
        </router-link>
      </mu-list>
    </mu-drawer>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      docked: false,
      open: false,
      position: "left",
      userinfo: {},
      // jsonFile: currentJsonFile
    };
  },
  methods: {
    switchPage(pageName) {
      this.$emit("switchPage", pageName);
    },
    // var employeeId = 12231;
    getJsonFile(employeeId) {
      this.currentJsonFile = require("../assets/json/" + employeeId + ".json");
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
```

The headerNav is as above. If I include this line "// jsonFile: currentJsonFile", the Nav Drawer (mu-drawer) will not open and it will show errors... like " Property or method "open" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
"

Comment: Do you use webpack? If so just `import` it

Comment: @l-portet There are a number of json files like 0001.json, 002.json... import must specify the path name so seems not a good way.

Comment: I see, I cannot answer properly for the moment but you should look about using `fetch` on your own resources. There are some good answers on StackOverflow with a quick search.